# USB C powered monitor drawing power while Mac is sleeping, how do I eject it / disable it?

Tags: usb, sleep-wake, power

My USB powered monitor draws power during sleep mode and depletes my battery overnight. The system is running macOS Sonoma 14.2.

I can use sleepwatcher to disable and enable my bluetooth on sleep / wake. What would a command look like to eject / disable and attach / enable a USB powered monitor? It would be handy to do the same with my mouse too.

Is this possible?

**Edit**
It seems like the problem is quite different to this, ie any monitor or a usb hub causes the problem so I've opened a new issue to describe the overall problem.

[After Sonoma 14.2.1 update, Macbook Pro 2018 doesn't sleep while usb leads attached](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/467675)

Comment: Are you closing the lid?

Comment: How is this question related to `bash`?  As for your problem how about disconnecting the monitor?

Comment: @user1934428 I removed bash, I guess it is not really related but I was hoping to create a bash script.

Comment: @benwiggy, no, I'm not closing the lid.  Just pressing the sleep from the apple menu.  If I close the lid it seems to confuse the displays a little (I'm using the main laptop display, one usb c powered monitor and one completely separate monitor)

Comment: Why not leave the laptop plugged-in overnight...?

Comment: because it uses up a lot of energy. Apple doesn't seem to cater for carbon emissions!

Comment: Why not unplug the monitor from the Mac overnight?

Comment: It seems to be anything plugged in that drains the battery (I thought initially it was just the usb powered monitor but I've tried with the usb hub too).  I have three leads plugged in (2 monitors and one usb hub with a mouse, usb stick and leads to connect my phone as and when I need).  I want to save energy as much as possible.  I can keep pulling the leads out whenever I have an hour's break from the machine and replugging them but that is inconvenient.

Comment: Any device plugged in to the computer will draw (a small amount) of power, even if it's asleep or unmounted. The only way to stop that is to physically disconnect the device.

Comment: It is not just the monitor, the question is actually quite different to the one here (although asking how to eject it could help).  It doesn't draw a small amount of power, it uses a large amount of power.  I don't think it is the monitor that is drawing the power, rather, any usb device plugged in is causing the laptop to use a lot of energy.  I created a new question here that is a better description of the problem.  See the screenshots.
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/467675/after-sonoma-14-2-1-update-macbook-pro-2018-doesnt-sleep-while-usb-leads-attac

Comment: Managed to fix the sleep drain battery problem  in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/467675

Comment: If the problem is solved then could we have this question marked as answered in some way?  Those with the same problem might want to know the solution, and people looking to offer answers could come here and be a bit disappointed to read through the commentary to find that they wasted time reading the background to find out that the problem was already solved.

Comment: Thanks @MacGuffin but the original question is not solved.  It would still be useful to find an answer to the question 'how do I eject / disable a monitor so it doesn't drain power'.  My main problem has been solved but the monitor still does draw a little bit of power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of what puts a computer to sleep is there's enough electronics powered somewhere for a rapid recovery.  Part of that rapid recovery is keeping the connection to the mouse and display active.  I can see how it might be inconvenient to disconnect all of the connected peripherals to avoid the "vampire" power draw.

I'd suggest a KVM switch as a way to disconnect all the peripherals with a push of a button.  (Something like this: https://www.startech.com/en-us/server-management/c2-d46-uc2-cbl-kvm  I'm not affiliated with the producer or retailer other than being a previous pleased customer.)

This might not eliminate all the "vampire" load since the switch needs power to operate.  A possible workaround for that is to plug the second computer input into something that can provide more power than the MacBook, a 5W, 12W or 20W power brick perhaps, just enough power to keep the KVM and attached devices in their own sleep mode.

Hit the switch on the KVM and everything is disconnected from your MacBook and instead drawing power from a power brick.  Switch them back to your MacBook and they are already to wake from their slumber and get to work.

If that isn't a acceptable solution then you may have to simply have to unplug everything from the laptop.  Even with a KVM switch there will be some power flow in or out (most likely out) to the KVM switch to indicate that there is something plugged in.

Maybe there's still some old style mechanical KVM switches around that will break any "vampire loads" but I suspect those would be rare and expensive.