# After Sonoma 14.2.1 update, Macbook Pro 2018 doesn't sleep while usb leads attached

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, battery, sleep-wake

My macbook pro isn't sleeping properly when I have usb devices attached.

I have a usb c powered monitor, mains powered monitor and a usb hub (currently just a mouse is attached and a printer which is switched off).  If any one of those usbs are attached, when the macbook is set to sleep, it stays on and the battery depletes after an hour or two.

I could pull all the leads out whenever I want the laptop to sleep but this is inconvenient.  I could leave the laptop on but that isn't good for the environment.  I could switch the laptop down but then I'd be waiting a few more minutes for the laptop to restart.

I check for is preventing sleep before I set the laptop to sleep.  I also disable and enable bluetooth using sleepwatcher.

How can I solve this problem?  I feel perhaps there is a setting to say, stay awake when usb leads are attached that has been reset after the MacOs update.

**Edit**
In the final graph below you can see the energy spiking and the battery rapidly depleting.  One strange point is that the laptop feels cool, usually if the processor is working hard the laptop feels hot.

**Edit2**
If I listen to the mac, it sounds as though a very quiet fan is working away.  It stops for a 5 seconds every couple of minutes and then almost immediately starts up again.

[image] [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With all options the same

```
pmset hibernatemode 25
```

to

```
pmset hibernatemode 3
```

and now my mac is sleeping properly.  Probably a bug in Sonoma 14.2.1 because it was working fine prior to the update.

Use `pmset -g` to view all sleep settings.

Comment: *"Probably a bug in Sonoma 14.2.1 ..."*.  It's a bug no doubt, but whether it's in the OS software or not - who knows really? When everything is closed source, and not even documented, speculation becomes fact.

Comment: I agree @Seamus, MacOS seems a bit opaque to say the least.  I called Apple support; they told me that I needed to go into an Apple shop to get it serviced and have the battery looked at.  Code is closed source, not documented and very likely they don't have a good testing regime as this should have been identified prior to shipping 14.2.1.  The MacOS code is not open source and even the bug updates are not open source; there seems to be no willingness or ability to log a bug with Apple.

Comment: I'm sometimes amused that *some people* in this SE seem to feel that this criticism is *anathema*. I get some good information here (and it's **appreciated**), but there are one or two here who come across as shamans or witch doctors. That's the real problem with closed source IMHO.

Comment: aye, good to be a realist and also constructive.